# When I try to retrieve a value from a PHP object it returns null

Tags: php, oop, null

Let's say the object is $Item. When I dump it using var_dump($Item) gives:

```
object(ProductVariation_OrderItem)[29]
  protected '_productVariationID' => string '6114' (length=4)
  protected '_productVariationVersion' => string '4' (length=1)
  protected '_productID' => string '4220' (length=4)
  protected '_productVersion' => string '72' (length=2)
  protected '_id' => null
  protected '_quantity' => string '1' (length=1)
  protected '_custom_text' => string 'erger ~~ gerger' (length=15)
  protected '_custom_text_id' => string 'b266dfceb5db66c01f08d97c45ebccf1' (length=32)
  public 'destroyed' => boolean false
  protected 'record' => 
    array
      'ID' => int 0
      'ClassName' => string 'ProductVariation_OrderItem' (length=26)
      'RecordClassName' => string 'ProductVariation_OrderItem' (length=26)
  protected 'changed' => 
    array
      empty
  protected 'original' => 
    array
      'ID' => int 0
      'ClassName' => string 'ProductVariation_OrderItem' (length=26)
      'RecordClassName' => string 'ProductVariation_OrderItem' (length=26)
  protected 'components' => null
  protected 'brokenOnWrite' => boolean false
  protected 'brokenOnDelete' => boolean false
  protected 'componentCache' => null
  protected 'iteratorPos' => int 0
  protected 'iteratorTotalItems' => int 1
  protected 'failover' => null
  protected '_object_cache' => 
    array
      empty
  protected '_xml_cache' => 
    array
      empty
  protected '_natural_cache' => 
    array
      empty
  protected 'customisedObj' => null
  protected 'parent' => null
  protected 'namedAs' => null
  public 'class' => string 'ProductVariation_OrderItem' (length=26)
  protected 'extension_instances' => 
    array
      empty
```

when I use use var_dump($Item->productVariationID) it returns 6114.. but when I use var_dump($Item->custom_text), It returns null.. I don't understand what is the problem here. Please someone explain me.

Comment: Do you have a magic method __get in your class?

Comment: NOpe.. I dont have any magic methods

Answer (score 0):

You have no `$Item->custom_text` nor `$Item->productVariationID` in your object

Comment: protected '_productVariationID' => string '6114' (length=4) .. what about this ?? It gives the value right ??

Comment: @ijasnijas: it is $Item->_productVariationID not $Item->_productVariationID - that'S the big difference!

Comment: WHat is the big difference ?? both are same right ?? You mean you skipped the underscore ??

Comment: @ijasnijas: yeah, that'S the difference